# Replace trigger words in a sentence

Tags: python, string

I have the following data:

```
 line = "This is a sample line"
 trigger_words = "sample"
```

What I would like to do now is screen through sentences to see if the line contains the trigger word. And if this is the case, replace it by "#"

Thefore I wrote the following code that allows me to find the first and last number in the sentence where the trigger_word is

```
if trigger in line:
 index = line.index(trigger)

 index_begin = index + 1
 index_eind = index + len(trigger) + 1
```

But now I am looking for a way to replace the part in the sentence from index_begin to index_end with "#".

Any thougths on how I can do this?

Comment: what you mean? you want this? "This is a ##### line" ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use *built-in* [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to achieve this as:

```
>>> line = "This is a sample line"
>>> trigger_words = "sample"

## If you want to replace the word with single '#' 
>>> line.replace(trigger_words, '#')
'This is a # line'  # returned string


## If you want to replace the word with '#' equivalent to length of word   
#                                  v- to repeat '#' equal to length 
#                                  v  of 'trigger_words'
>>> line.replace(trigger_words, '#'*len(trigger_words))
'This is a ###### line'  # returned string
```

Answer (score 0):

The string in python is actually list, so you can leverage the string using splice. Like below:

```
line = line[:index_begin] + '#' + line[index_end:]
```

NOTE: Do not add 1 to index if you use this method.